# Ошибка при чтение txt файла в python 3.9.5

Tags: python

изучаю книгу Зед А. Шоу "Легкий способ выучить Python 3" и дошел до упражнения "Чтение файлов", но столкнулся с проблемой. Ввел код из книжки и проверил все досконально.
Вот код из книги:

```py
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

txt = open(filename, 'r')

print(f"Содержимое файла {filename:}")
print(txt.read())

print("Снова введите имя файла:")
file_again = input("> ")

txt_again = open(file_again)
print(txt_again.read())*
```

Я хотел запустить python и txt файл одновременно но выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Amirhamza\python\IBRONOV\FirstProg.py", line 59, in <module>
    print(txt.read())
  File "C:\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 112: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: `txt = open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8')` так попробуйте

Comment: ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬЬЬЬЬЬЬЬЬЬЬЬ! Спасибо друг, неделю искал в инете не мог найти ошибку. Дай бог тебе здоровья!

Comment: Вы ещё и файлы не закрываете после использования. Лучше закрывать. Или использовать with

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Лучше использовать контекстный менеджер `with`. С ним не придется думать о том, что файл надо не только открыть, но еще и закрыть после чтения. Также параметр `r`, можно не указывать при открытии файла, т.к. файлы по-умолчанию открываются в этом режиме.

```py
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    print(f'Содержимое файла {filename:}')
    print(file.read())
```

А еще в вашем коде одновременно используются и двойные и одинарные кавычки, лучше остановиться на каком-то одном варианте и придерживаться его.